# Run command after finding result using FOR /f

Tags: batch

I want to run the command when finding the result but it seems it did not work. Our computer names are something like HS-33-123-WC, HS-34-456-X  The result seems not go to the one that I want. It seems that I did not make the right script     if  %%a==WC goto dhcp and if %%a==X goto static

```
REM Display the 4th group of character(s) after -
wmic computersystem get name
for /f "tokens=4 delims=-" %%a in ("%computername%") do (echo %%a && goto next)


:next
if  %%a==WC goto dhcp
if %%a==X goto static


:static
echo Static
pause
goto end

:dhcp
echo This is DHCP
pause
goto end
```

:end
@exit /b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@echo off
REM Display the 4th group of character(s) after -

for /f "tokens=4 delims=-" %%a in ("%computername%") do (
                                                         echo "%%a"
                                                         set Var=%%a
                                                        )

if  "%Var%"=="WC" goto dhcp
if "%Var%"=="X" goto static
:end
exit

:static
echo Static
pause
goto end

:dhcp
echo This is DHCP
pause
goto end
```

Answer (score 1):

`%%a` is only available inside the loop.

You should inside the loop, set a local variable to it. Add the command:

```
set var=%%a
```

then use `%var%` in the following code.